# How to set the form position and font size in a KOL form

Tags: delphi, properties, kol

I have two questions about KOL.

1. I have a main form. As I see this placed on the TForm's position.
   I wanna put it to the screen center.
   How can I access it's coordinates, or the handle for "SetWindowPos"?
2. I have 4 labels in the form. For 2 of them I want to use smaller fonts. But I don't found any Font Size property... How to do it then?

Comment: It's better to ask just one question at a time, as per the [faq]

Comment: IF you use KOL then why don't you use MCK ? MCK should provide for specifying font in design-time.

Comment: @durumdara You've asked 66 questions here now. Take a look at the effort TLama put into his excellent answer. You have voted once only. 66 questions, and 1 vote. That is poor. You should engage more.

Comment: Sorry for two questions at once. Very-very thanks for every info!

Comment: As well as saying thank you, please learn to vote and accept answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***1.1. How to center form on screen ?***

Use the `CenterOnForm` method. As description says, if it's applied to a form, centers form on screen:

```
Form.CenterOnForm(nil);
```

---

***1.2. How to get form position ?***

Just like in Delphi by the `Left` and `Top` properties or e.g. by the `Position` property. The following pseudo-code results to the same:

```
ShowMessage('Form pos.: [' +
  Int2Str(Form.Left) + '; ' +
  Int2Str(Form.Top) + ']'
);
ShowMessage('Form pos: [' +
  Int2Str(Form.Position.X) + '; ' +
  Int2Str(Form.Position.Y) + ']'
);
```

Note, that unless you change the form position by yourself or until the applet is running, both properties returns 0. The form position, if you didn't set it, is adjusted when the applet starts.

---

***1.3. How to get form handle ?***

Use either the `Handle` property or the `GetWindowHandle` method. The following pseudo-code results to the same:

```
ShowMessage(Int2Str(Form.Handle));
ShowMessage(Int2Str(Form.GetWindowHandle));
```

---

***2. How to change the font size ?***

As @David already mentioned in his post, use the `Font.FontHeight` property. Just one sidenote, the default font when you create e.g. that label is set to `System` to which is not possible to change the size, so don't be surprised when the size changes won't be applied. Here's a quote from the source:

> Value 0 (default) says to use system default value, negative values
>   are to represent font height in "points", positive - in pixels. In XCL
>   usually positive values (if not 0) are used to make appearance
>   independent from different local settings.

And here's a sample usage shown on positioned label creation:

```
Label1 := NewLabel(Form, 'Label1').SetPosition(8, 8);
Label1.Font.FontName := 'Tahoma';
Label1.Font.FontHeight := -11;
```

---

***3. Example project***

```
program Project1;

uses
  KOL;

type
  PForm1 = ^TForm1;
  TForm1 = object(TObj)
    Form, Label1, Label2, Label3, Label4: PControl;
  end;

var
  Form1: PForm1;

procedure CreateForm(var Result: PForm1; AParent: PControl);
begin
  New(Result, Create);
  with Result^ do
  begin
    Form := NewForm(AParent, 'Caption').SetSize(320, 240);
    Form.CenterOnForm(nil);

    Label1 := NewLabel(Form, 'Label1').SetPosition(8, 8);
    Label1.Font.FontName := 'Tahoma';
    Label1.Font.FontHeight := -11;
    Label2 := NewLabel(Form, 'Label2').SetPosition(72, 8);
    Label2.Font.FontName := 'Tahoma';
    Label2.Font.FontHeight := -11;
    Label3 := NewLabel(Form, 'Label3').SetPosition(136, 8);
    Label3.Font.FontName := 'Tahoma';
    Label3.Font.FontHeight := -15;
    Label4 := NewLabel(Form, 'Label4').SetPosition(200, 8);
    Label4.Font.FontName := 'Tahoma';
    Label4.Font.FontHeight := -15;
  end;
end;

begin
  Applet := NewApplet('Test');
  CreateForm(Form1, Applet);
  Run(Applet);
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

Call the SetPosition and SetSize methods on the form.

```
Form.SetPosition(x,y);
Form.SetSize(w,h);
```

**Question 2**

Use `Font.FontHeight`.

```
MyControl.Font.FontHeight := ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to call SetWindowPos, you can retrieve the handle calling the GetWindowHandle method of the returned pointer.
2. Please, don't ask more than 1 question per question.